# how to create 3 connected buttons?

Tags: android, android-layout, button

we are using eclipse for developing an android app and we simply wants to create 3 buttons that connected to each other. this is the MyActivity .xml ,this look like this, but we want to do button need button without space.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />
```

Here is the Image

[image: Valid XHTML].

Answer (score 2):

you can set margin for that.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />
```

set minus margin and check your result.

Answer (score 2):

Use a LinearLayout with the buttons inside.

```
<LinearLayout
     <Button/>
     <Button/>
     <Button/>
/>
```

you can then align the LinearLayout as you wish (center, right, left,...)

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout and center it 
then inside the RelativeLayout , create 3 Buttons (button1 , button2 , button3 )
and give them the following attributes :
1- button1
alignParentLeft=true , to TotheLeftOf=button2
2- button2 :
toTHeRightOf=button1 , totheLeftOf=button3
3- button3 :
totheRightOf = button2 , alignparentRight = true .

Hope thats helps

Answer (score 0):

just use like this   `android:layout_weight="1"`in every button

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Button3" />
</LinearLayout>
```